# How to determine subsets of sigma-algebra?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $\Omega$ and suppose that $B \in  \mathcal{F}$. Show that $\mathcal{G} = \{A \cap B : A \in \mathcal{F} \}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra of subsets of $B$.

My approach. Not sure about whether is complete:
First we have to show that $\mathcal{G} $ satisfies the properties of a $\sigma$-algebra, that is:

$\emptyset \in \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow \emptyset=\emptyset \cap B \in \mathcal{G}$

If $A_1,A_2,...A_n,... \in  \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow \bigcup\limits_i
 (A_i \cap B)=(\bigcup\limits_i A_i)\cap B \in \mathcal{G} $

If $A \in \mathcal{F} \Rightarrow A^c \in \mathcal{F}$  thus $B \setminus A \cap B=A^c\cap B \in \mathcal{G} $

Not sure whether its enough

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is enough. Note that you have not used anywhere the fact that $B \in \mathcal F$, you merely used that $B \subseteq X$. This $\sigma$-algebra is called the **trace** of $\mathcal F$ on $B$ or the **restriction** of $\mathcal F$ to $B$.

You can also check that if $i : B \to X$ denotes the inclusion map, then your $\sigma$-algebra is merely $i^* \mathcal F$ (i.e. the pullback of the $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ along $i$).

Hope that helps,